# For the final temple, who will The-Prince | הַנָּשִׂ֗יא Ha-Nasi from [Ezekiel 44:3, 46:12] be since [Hebrews 7:27, 8:4] claims it can't be Jesus?

Tags: hebrews, prophecy, ezekiel, temple

**The Prince | הַנָּשִׂ֗יא Ha-Nasi in [Ezekiel 44:3] will be a future High Priest serving in the earthly Temple of HaShem forever.**

Yechezekel יְחֶזְקֵ֨אל | "Ezekiel" [44:3]

> " The prince - [a] prince - He shall sit therein to eat bread before HaShem ; by the way of the hall of the gate he shall come, and by the same way he shall leave. " ( אֶֽת־הַנָּשִׂ֗יא נָ֥שִׂיא ה֛וּא יֵֽשֶׁב־בּ֥וֹ לֶאֱכָול־לֶ֖חֶם לִפְנֵ֣י יְהוָ֑ה מִדֶּ֨רֶךְ אֻלָ֤ם הַשַּׁ֙עַר֙ יָב֔וֹא וּמִדַּרְכּ֖וֹ יֵצֵֽא )

- This eternal Prince was required by God to make sacrifices in the eternal Temple in [Ezekiel 46:12].

**Yet we learn in Hebrews 7:27 - "Jesus" would not be The Prince of Ezekiel 44, since we are told Jesus as a heavenly High Priest does not make anymore sacrifices. Hebrews 8:4 claims Jesus wouldn't be a priest at all [on earth].**

Hebrews 7:27 [NASB] :

> "Unlike the other high priests, he [Jesus] *does not need to offer sacrifices day after day, first for his own sins, and then for the sins of the people. He sacrificed for their sins once for all when he offered himself."

Hebrews 8:4 [NASB]:

> "Now if He [Jesus] were on earth, He would not be a priest at all"

For the final earthly temple, who will The-Prince | הַנָּשִׂ֗יא Ha-Nasi from [Ezekiel 44:3] & [Ezekiel 46:12] be since [Hebrews 7:27, 8:4] claims it cannot be Jesus?

Comment: Jesus is a High Priest after the order of Melchizedek. This ‘order’ does not make sacrifices. It’s only the Levtical priesthood that sacrifices for sin. In the times of the final earthly temple, the tribes will have already returned to Israel.

Comment: This is like saying that, since Jesus was not a literal lamb, the sacrifices of lambs in the Mozaic covenant do not prefigure Christ's sacrifice. Please note that the very text you quoted has ***other** high priests*.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Paul is teaching that in this new covenant all matters are fulfilled (completed not abolished) spiritually.  There is therefore no physical temple & no point to Christ offering physical sacrifices as the sacrifices in this new covenant are now spiritual.

The support for a spiritual vs physical temple is found in:

> Revelation 21:22  I did not see a temple in the city (no physical temple), because the Lord God Almighty and the Lamb are its (spiritual) temple.

> Ephesians 2:20-22  Built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, with Christ Jesus himself as the chief cornerstone (of this spiritual temple).  21 In him the whole building (spiritual temple) is joined together and rises to become a holy temple in the Lord.

> John 2:19-21  Jesus answered them, "Destroy this temple, and I will raise it again in three days (as chief cornerstone of the spiritual temple)."  20 They replied, "It has taken forty-six years to build this temple, and you are going to raise it in three days?"  21 But the temple he had spoken of was his body.

> 1Corinthians 6:19  Do you not know that your bodies are temples of the holy spirit who is in you, whom you have received from God? You are not your own;

We are joined together as a spiritual temple in the Kingdom of Heaven.

In Hebrews 8:4 Paul is making the point that in this new covenant the physical sacrifices are replaced by spiritual sacrifices.  In the same chapter Paul (Hebrews 8:6-13) states we now have a new and superior covenant and high priest.

Physical sacrifices were never the point.  It was our obedience to His Holy Laws & Commandments which is considered our spiritual sacrifice.

> Micah 6:6-8  With what shall I come before the lord and bow down before the exalted God? Shall I come before him with burnt offerings, with calves a year old?  7  Will the lord be pleased with thousands of rams, with ten thousand rivers of olive oil? Shall I offer my firstborn for my transgression, the fruit of my body for the sin of my soul?  8  He has shown you, O mortal, what is good. And what does the lord require of you? To act justly and to love mercy and to walk humbly with your God.

> 1Samuel 15:22  But Samuel replied: "Does the lord delight in burnt offerings and sacrifices as much as in obeying the lord? To obey (our spiritual sacrifice) is better than (physical) sacrifice, and to heed is better than the fat of rams.

Lets conclude with a verse just 6 verses after the verse you cited (Hebrews 8:4).

> Hebrews 8:10  This is the covenant I will establish with the people of Israel after that time, declares the Lord. I will put my laws in their minds and write them on their hearts. I will be their God, and they will be my people.

In Hebrews 8 Paul teaching this new covenant with greater promises & a superior High Priest & our spiritual sacrifice governed by the gift of a loving heart to keep His Laws.

Comment: If you believe the future Temple in [Ezekiel] on earth is only ‘spiritual’ & Paul wrote [Hebrews], then I respect your own beliefs. * Do you also believe by offering [1 Corinthians 6:19, Ephesians 2] as an answer that only the ‘spiritual’ body of believers on earth are Ezekiel’s future Temple, making the Word of HaShem through Ezekiel’s prophecy inaccurate/false?

Comment: God has revealed His plan for mankind progressively over time and through covenants.  The nature of this new covenant hadn't been completely revealed to Ezekiel.  However in the book of Ezekiel we do not see the temple being constructed until after chapter 39 the great battle and cleansing of the land.  Why? because now the resurrection of the dead had taken place so the (spiritual) construction could take place.

Answer (score 0):

Ezekiel 44:

> 3
> The **prince** himself is the only one who may sit inside the gateway to eat in the presence of the LORD. He is to enter by way of the portico of the gateway and go out the same way.”

For the final temple, who will The-Prince | הַנָּשִׂ֗יא Ha-Nasi from [Ezekiel 44:3, 46:12] be since [Hebrews 7:27, 8:4] claims it can't be Jesus?

Pulpit explains:

> That the "prince" here alluded to (הַגָּשִׂיא) could not have been the Prince David, i.e. the Messiah already spoken of (Ezekiel 34:23, 24; Ezekiel 37:24), but must have denoted the civic authorities of the new community of Israel, "**the civil head of the theocracy**," Havernick infers from Ezekiel 45:8, 9, where the coming "prince" is contrasted with Israel's previous rulers who oppressed their subjects, from the absence of some such characteristic predicate as "shepherd" or "king," which would, he thinks, have been attached to the word "prince"